# How to display php variables in fopen() file and not php variable values

Tags: php, html

I am writing scripts for my clients to download. The script is working but I am battling to create a downloadable file containing the correct php code. The script to create the file is working and it downloads the file, but the content is not showing correct.

Short exampleof current code and issue

**Code:**

```
$file = "test.php";
$txt = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$content = "
<?php
$variable1 = $variable2;
$directory = getcwd();
?>";
fwrite($txt, $content);
fclose($txt);
```

I want to see `$variable1 = $variable2;` and `$directory = getcwd();` not the values of the variables.

Currently the test page is showing for eg:
`= domain/path/to/current/folder` instead of `$directory = getcwd();`

Also, when I want to create a variable which has not been defined, like `$directory = getcwd();` it does not show `$directory`

How do I display the actual code with variable names and not the value of the variable.

My next step after this is to encrypt the code using tools such as phpbolt or  pH-7 Obfuscator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` if you want to have that as a string instead of working PHP code.

```
$content = '
<?php
$variable1 = $variable2;
$directory = getcwd();
?>';
```

Or escape dollar signs.

```
$content = "
<?php
\$variable1 = \$variable2;
\$directory = getcwd();
?>";
```

Notice: I can't imagine a real usage of this code (creating test.php content this way).

Due to comment below, if you need to use any variable value, it can be

```
$content = '
<?php
$variable1 = "' . $variable2 . '";
$directory = getcwd();
?>';

// Output: <?php $variable1 = "ABCD"; $directory = getcwd()
```

If it should be integer value, remove `"`. If you don't need semicolon, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first one and it worked perfectly.However, I forgot to add, only one variable need to display variable value and not variable name: `$SoftwareToken = ' . '$UniqueSoftwareToken' . ';`. Can you kindly assist me again. The variable $UniqueSoftwareToken is from a mysql  query.

Comment: @Charlie I've updated answer

Comment: I have been battling for about an hour and you sorted this out in a few minutes. Many thanks. Have you used any php obfuscators before like phpbolt or pH-7 Obfuscator? If so, which would you suggest?

Comment: @Charlie: sorry, I'm not PHP developer, don't know any obfuscators etc. Just basic ;-)

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score -1):

the content need some changes:

```
$file = "test.php";
$content = '<?php
                $variable1 = ' . '$variable2' . ';
                $directory = getcwd();
            ?>';
    if ($size = file_put_contents($file, $content)) {
        echo "success";
    }
```

Comment: `$v = "$";` - thas really isn't the right way how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your review,I updated the way I wrote the code

Comment: There is no reason for joining strings on line 3. Than your vodě will be the samé as mine.

Comment: If the strings do not join together and variable2 is entered as a variable according to the above answer, it is not supported in the created file, unless it is set in the constructor file, in which case you are right.